# navbar + tabbar problems

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

This is a part of my storyboard:
[image: navbar+tabbar]

The "Sign In" ViewController is embedded in TabBarController, which is embedded in Navigation Controller.

If I'm performing a segue from SignInVC to another VC, the navbar flickers and it's not done smoothly.

If I'm changing the order -  Sign in embedded in NavController which is embedded in TabBar, everything works well.

What can cause this behavior?

**Edit:**

The "problem" with the second approach is that every VC would contain the tabbar items - If I'm performing a segue from SignInVC to another VC, that other VC would also contain the tabbar..

Comment: The second one is the right approach, every instance of Tabbar contains a stack and when embedded in navigation controller it gives each stack a navigation hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, you might be right but see the part I've added to the question

Comment: Every VC contain a new tabbar? OR Do you want the tabbar visible below every VC? Also a visual can better help to understand.

Comment: At the second approach every VC would contain the bottom tabbar, which I don't want. I want only the first view to contain the tabbar.

Comment: What if you stop the animation of segue set animation value false. Have you tried that?

Comment: You could use the second approach and set the hidesbottombarwhenpushed property to true if you don't want the tabbar on the pushed viewControllers. It really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I've tried setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true, at the storyboard and also at prepare(for segue:...) func, but the bar won't disappear :(

Comment: What ViewController are you "pushing to" from the TabBarController, and how are you doing so?